# React app with proxy doesn't work on heroku, but previous app does?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I've been working on a MERN stack app, created using create-react-app, and its the second one I've built - the first one is on heroku and works fine.  The architecture is the same as the first, and I've deployed it to heroku, but when I browse to the app, I get an Invalid Host Header error.  Both have a proxy set to localhost:3001 in the package.json so the front end and back end can communicate.

I've read a lot of threads around similar questions, most seem to be from 2017-2018, and discuss issues around removing the proxy, using http proxy middleware and versions of webpack server.  I'm trying to understand why the earlier react app is working on heroku with a proxy if that approach shouldn't work or isn't recommended.  I have been trying to analyze differences between the two apps, especially in server.js and package.json, but I haven't identified anything significant - the first app was built in October and served as a template for the second.

I have a procfile, heroku environment variables are set, nothing weird happened when I `npm run build`.  .env contains variables for secret and database, but host is not defined there, which seems to be something I had seen suggested in other threads.

[github is here:](https://github.com/mhwhite22/forescore-react)

The server.js looks like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const logger = require("morgan");
const favicon = require("serve-favicon");

const app = express();

require("dotenv").config();
require("./config/database");

const coursesRouter = require("./routes/api/courses");
const roundsRouter = require("./routes/api/rounds");

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, "build", "favicon.ico")));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));

// API Routes here
app.use("/api/users", require("./routes/api/users"));
app.use("/api/courses", require("./routes/api/courses"));
app.use("/api/rounds", require("./routes/api/rounds"));

app.use(require("./config/auth"));

// catchall
app.get("/*", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log(`Express app running on port ${port}`);
});
```

and the package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "forescore-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.13",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-date-picker": "^8.0.5",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-materialize": "^3.9.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see here you have used a common package.json for both frontend and backend but I didn't find any script in your package.json file to start the backend server i.e. there should be a command `node server.js`.

In your case, you are not starting your backend server so your API calls must be failing.

Also, there is no `"heroku-postbuild"` script which is also required.

You can go through this article which provides a step-by-step guide to deploy a MERN app to Heroku.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/deploying-a-mern-application-using-mongodb-atlas-to-heroku/

Comment: Isn't that the purpose of the content of the procfile ( 'web: node server.js' )?

Edit:  My procfile was named in lower case, and apparently this was causing heroku to ignore it, so there is no command to start the backend server, as you point out.  I think I need to figure out how to get the change in case in the file name to push to heroku.